# Android Save High Scores

Tags: java, android

What's up guys I'm developing a game for Android and I have one problem that I didn't find in internet.I want to save the high score with shared preferences and that is the code:

```
Play Class : 
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putInt("key", score);
        edit.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HighScore.class);
        startActivity(it);
```

And this is the high score list code :

```
highscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore_int);
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 
                                                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int score = prefs.getInt("key", 0); //0 is the default value
highscore.setText(""+score);
```

This works fine but it saves all scores even it's smaller than previous.  I want to save the score only if it's bigger than previous.  How can I do that?
PS : Sorry for my English and I don't know how to highlight the code :(

Comment: You ran on a problem that you couldn't find on the internet - did you try searching "how to determine which number is bigger of the two?" because that's what you need to do. Check the current score vs the one from shared preferences, and go with the bigger one.

Comment: Yes but how to check previous number I save the scores with one name

Comment: First, compare the scores. If new score is bigger than the saved one, change it; else do nothing

Comment: I know this but how can I do that with this code I tried this
if(score > score) {//save score}
but it didn't work

Comment: How can I get the old score I saved the scores with same name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int oldScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0);  
if(newScore > oldScore ){
   Editor edit = prefs.edit();
   edit.putInt("key", newScore);
   edit.commit();
}
```

to see.